# Find all solutions to this system such that $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6$ are each equal only to 1, 0, or -1.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The system in question is the following:

$x_1 - x_5 = 0$

$x_2 - x_5 - x_6=0$

$x_3 -x_5 - x_6=0$

$x_4-x_5-x_6=0$

Letting $x_5$ and $x_6$ be some real numbers $k$ and $t$, respectively, I can find a general solution:

$S = \left \{k\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}| k, t \in \mathbb{R} \right \}.$

But how do I find all the solutions such that each $x_i$ is equal only to $1, 0$ or $-1$? Furthermore, how might I show that those solutions are linear combinations of the general solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: 
The idea of a general solution is to be a function which, if you substitute in all (in this case real) values, yields all solutions. Every substitution of values into the general solution (i.e. each substitution of $k,t$) is a linear combination.
Therefore, all possible solutions are linear combinations of the general solution, and by that especially all solutions containing only values in $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Second: 
To be completely formal, the restriction on the solutions you want can be seen as a series of systems of equations:

Starting from the initial series of equations, your general solution is technically nothing different than another system of equation (though one which uses the minimal amount of necessary variables). So, one method would be to do for every vector $c\in \{-1,0,1\}^6$:
$$
k\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} = c
$$

Given that this system of equations is oversaturated, there is only a finite amount of solutions, so for each $c$ you could calculate them all.

However, that's a lot of work to do. An easier method would be to look only at the first and second row in the system of equations and  solve it for $\{-1,0,1\}$. As we've got only 2 variables, this already yields all possible solutions, we now only have to filter those, who don't work out.

Comment: Very  helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The equations can be trivially reduced, namely to $x_5=x_1$, then $x_6=x_2-x_1$ and $x_4=x_3=x_2$. So we are done.

Comment: I do see that, but how can I find all solutions such that each variable is restricted only to -1, 0, or 1?

Comment: You only have to assign $x_1,x_2$ every possible value in $0,1,-1$ and then you see immediately what is  $x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$. Only $x_6$ could be a problem, i.e., not be in $\{0,1,-1\}$. This is very easy to verify. So $x_2=1$ and $x_1=-1$ is not possible, for example.

Comment: Dietrich, thanks for your reply. That makes a lot more sense. I will give it a shot now.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at $x_5$  and $x_6$, we need $k,t\in\{-1,0,1\}$. Clearly, $k=t=\pm1$ leads to $x_2=\pm2$. The other seven cases give valid solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Must I go through each case, or is there a more systematic method? Furthermore, how might I show that each solution is a linear combination of the general solution?